# function returns None, even if I have return command

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a function to test whether a string is palindrome or not:

```
def palindrome(raw_text):
    # first to convert raw_text to a string of lower case letters and remove the space
    text = raw_text.lower()
    text = text.replace(' ', '')

    print('text is now', text)
    print('length of text is', len(text))
    if len(text) == 1 or len(text) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        if text[0] == text[-1]:
            print('so far so good')
            palindrome(text[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
```

To make it clear for debug, I added a few print command to help me.
if I try:

```
raw_text = 'abcba'
print(palindrome(raw_text))
```

I will get:

```
text is now abcba
length of text is 5
so far so good
text is now bcb
length of text is 3
so far so good
text is now c
length of text is 1
None
```

So why am I getting a None at the end? I did have the `return True` command for `len(text) == 1 or 0`

If I just give `raw_text = 'a'`, it will give me:

```
text is now a
length of text is 1
True
```

Comment: BTW, you could do this easily without recursion... unless this is an exercise in learning about recursion.

Comment: @PM2Ring this is indeed to practice recursion. Otherwise, I'll just use [::-1] to compare. THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to recurse properly.

```
return palindrome(text[1:-1])
```

Comment: GOt it !!! Thanks!!! So this is more about the recursion. I need to add that keyword to the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentioned, I did not recurse properly.
Actually the code does not need to be this complicate.
I have revised it to:

```
def palindrome(raw_text):
    # first to convert raw_text to a string of lower case letters and remove the space
    text = raw_text.lower()
    text = text.replace(' ', '')

    print('text is now', text)
    print('length of text is', len(text))

    if len(text) <= 3:
        return text[0] == text[-1]
    else:
        return text[0] == text[-1] and palindrome(text[1:-1])
```